# Product Image Upload button missing

Tags: products-management, image-upload

I am working on magento 1.9.2.2 and with latest version of chrome 46.0.2490.71 but it is showing

> http://xyz.xyz.xyz/xyz/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
>   403 (Forbidden)

uploader.swf was present in adminhtml/default/default/media  folder
and permission provided is **777**

Comment: I don't know exactly just try with different browser or update your browser latest version

Comment: i'm using chrome and Firefox both are not working

Comment: update your browser latest version